# Identify Shapes with Matlab 

Tags: matlab, shapes

I created some MATLAB code, that find somes shapes in an image
using **`regionpros`** and **`bwbounaries`**   functions.

I have:

```
STATS = regionprops(L, 'all');
```

and from `STATS` I could easily find all my shapes Area and Perimeter.
My problem is    the following: I want to find the "square" shapes and I do 
in all shapes the following calculation `16 * area / (perimeter * perimeter)`, 
if this value is near one then I "may"                      have a square. But other shapes too like
circles or rectangles are near one too. (Also some squares could be rotated
in the image).

Is there a better way to distinguish the shapes (like circles, triangles ...)?

Answer (score 2):

Matlab has a function

```
procrustes(X,Y)
```

which will compute distance between two shapes based on the types of transformations it would take to move the points defined by X onto the points defined by Y. For many shape classification tasks, minimizing this distance is a useful way of categorizing noisy instances of shapes. If your problem has 'perfect' shapes, this should work extremely well. Just have Y fixed as a perfect square, and any time that the linear transformation from X to Y is a pure scaling, then you know X is also a square. You could do some simple logical checking to select only shapes satisfying this sort of property.

Comment: The Python package PyGeometry has a similar Procrustes optimization function if you're ever doing this stuff in Python.